# Parsing RSS Enclosure URL - PHP

Tags: php, rss

So I'm facing a very odd situation where I am trying to parse the enclosure url from an RSS feed for a particular item. I need the link to the image attachment.  However, all the methods I have been trying are providing me with the actual article link vice the image link.

```
<item> <title>Patches of Snow on the Red Planet</title>
<link>http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/patches-of-snow-on-the-red- 
planet</link>
<description>In early Martian summer, at the time NASA&#039;s Mars 
Reconnaissance Orbiter acquired this image, the dunes are almost free of 
their seasonal ice cover.</description>
<enclosure 
url="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/marssnow.jpg" 
length="516834" type="image/jpeg" />
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/patches-of-snow- 
on-the-red-planet</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 05 Jun 2018 15:06 EDT</pubDate>
<source url="http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss">NASA Image of 
the Day</source>
</item>
```

I've tried all sorts of permuations of

```
$this->enclosure->url;

$this->enclosure['url'];
```

etc.

Even when I try to get the enclosure length, I still get back the article url.

I get back the "link" url and not the enclosure url.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: what library are you using anyway? SimpleXML or `DOM`?

Answer (score 1):

You should using 
`getElementsByTagName('enclosure')` to get DOM Element by Tag Name
after that using `getAttribute('url')` for get url from `enclosure` tag

My code

```php
<?php
// XML test 
$xml = <<< XML
<item> <title>Patches of Snow on the Red Planet</title>
<link>http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/patches-of-snow-on-the-red- 
planet</link>
<description>In early Martian summer, at the time NASA&#039;s Mars 
Reconnaissance Orbiter acquired this image, the dunes are almost free of 
their seasonal ice cover.</description>
<enclosure 
url="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/marssnow.jpg" 
length="516834" type="image/jpeg" />
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/patches-of-snow- 
on-the-red-planet</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 05 Jun 2018 15:06 EDT</pubDate>
<source url="http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss">NASA Image of 
the Day</source>
</item>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$ens = $dom->getElementsByTagName('enclosure');

foreach ($ens as $en)
{
    // you can debug here
    echo $en->getAttribute('url');
}
```